# Entity Framework: Added view appears in Model Browser but not Solution Explorer

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have a project which uses Entity Framework. I've added a view from my SQL Server database to the model using the Model Browser in Visual Studio 2012 such that it appears under the following items:

1. Entity Types under my model.
2. Entity Container, Entity Sets
3. .Store, Tables / Views

However, I can't access it from my code.

Back in Solution Explorer, under the Models folder, the view does not appear anywhere under the EDMX file for my model (though it DOES appear in the diagram).

I can not seem to find any practical way to add the view to my data model such that it is usable. Ultimately, I want to reference it via the entities object so I can select data from it.

Answer (score 0):

Every Entity in EF should have unique identifier. Try to select a key column in view and then try to add view. View should be available to you